# How can I find occurences in a list?

Tags: python, list, function, return, bioinformatics

I´m working on an assigment in Python, and I have a question if you could answer. 
I wanna write a function that returns a list with the locations of the first nucleotide of all occurrences of "ATG" in the sequence.
For example, we can say that our DNA sequence is A**A**TGC**A**TGC. We see that ATG can start in the index 1, and the other possibility is index 5. 
I tried this one to solve this assignment;

```
dna = "AATGCATGC"
starting_offset = dna.index("ATG")
print(starting_offset)
```

The result I´ve got is 1. But I wanna get result as [1, 5]

So how should I write this function for all occurrences?

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: sounds like a job for itertools - search python & itertools and look through the api

Comment: if you want to do it yourself: find the first occurence [x] - there is no possible in match match (cant find ATG starting inside of one find) so create a shorter string from your find position + len(ATG) and find the next index. accumulate them until less then len(ATG) characters left.

Comment: @strawberry: example of that approach see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions, you can use re.finditer to find all occurences:

You can try this function :

```
import re
text = 'AATGCATGC'
pattern='ATG'
def getIndexes (text,pattern):
    list=[index.start() for index in re.finditer('ATG', text)]
    return list
getIndexes(text,pattern)
>>[1, 5]
```

It will gives you the list you're looking for . Hope that'll be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to think about, analyse this:

```
def GetMultipleInString(dna, term):
    # computing end condition 0
    if (term not in dna):
        print (dna + " does not contain the term " + term)
        return []

    # start of list of lists of 2 elements: index, rest
    result = [[None,dna]]

    # we look for the index in the rest, need to keep track how much we
    # shortened the string in total so far to get index in complete string
    totalIdx = 0

    # we look at the last element of the list until it's length is shorter
    # than the term we look for (end of computing condition 1)
    termLen = len(term)

    while len(result[-1][1]) >= termLen:
        # get the last element
        last = result[-1][1]
        try:
            # find our term, if not found -> exception
            idx = last.index(term) 
            # partition "abcdefg" with "c" -> ("ab","c", "defg")
            # we take only the remaining 
            rest = last.partition(term)[2] 
            # we compute the total index, and put it in our result
            result.append( [idx+totalIdx , rest] ) 
            totalIdx += idx+termLen 
        except:
            result.append([None,last])
            break

    # any results found that are not none? 
    if (any( x[0] != None for x in result)):

        print (dna + " contains the term " + term + " at positions:"),
        # get only indexes from our results
        rv = [ str(x[0]) for x in result if x[0] != None]
        print (' '.join(rv))

        return rv

    else:
        print (dna + " does not contain the term " + term)
        return []

print("_----------------------------------_")
myDna = "AATGCATGC"  
res1 = GetMultipleInString(myDna,"ATG")   
print(res1)

res2 = GetMultipleInString(myDna,"A")
print(res2)
```